# How to make progress bar value by calculating the time of process using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I have a powershell with windows form.
I need to use progress bar to check the progress of the process.

I've tried, but the percentage of the progress bar unable to start from 0 - 100%.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "PowerShell GUI"
$form.Width = 400
$form.Height = 150

# Create Progress Bar
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Name = "Begin"
$progressBar.Style = "Continuous"
$progressBar.Width = 350
$progressBar.Height = 20
$progressBar.Top = 50
$progressBar.Left = 20

# Create Label for percentage display
$labelPercentage = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelPercentage.AutoSize = $true
$labelPercentage.Text = "0%"
$labelPercentage.Top = 75
$labelPercentage.Left = 200

# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($progressBar)
$form.Controls.Add($labelPercentage)

# Function to update the progress bar
function Update-ProgressBar {
    param (
        [int]$Percentage
    )

    $progressBar.Value = $Percentage
    $labelPercentage.Text = "$Percentage%"
    $form.Refresh()
}

# Function to execute the process and update progress
function Execute-ProcessAndUpdateProgressBar {
    $startTime = Get-Date

    function GetUUTInfo {
        $logFilePath = ".\UUT.log"
        if (Test-Path $logFilePath) {
            # Your code to process UUT info if the log file exists
        } else {
            # Your code if the log file does not exist
        }
    }

    try {
        $process = Start-Process .\Utility.exe /getconfig:.\UUT.log -PassThru -Wait
        $endTime = Get-Date
        $elapsedTime = ($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds

        # Adjust this value based on the expected duration of your process
        $expectedDuration = 1

        while ($elapsedTime -lt $expectedDuration) {
            $percentage = [math]::Round(($elapsedTime / $expectedDuration) * 100)
            Update-ProgressBar -Percentage $percentage
            $elapsedTime = (Get-Date - $startTime).TotalSeconds
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        }

        # Ensure the progress bar reaches 100%
        Update-ProgressBar -Percentage 100
        GetUUTInfo
    } catch {
        GetUUTInfo
    }
}

# Show the Form
$form.Add_Shown({
    Execute-ProcessAndUpdateProgressBar
    $form.Close()
})

$form.ShowDialog()
```

my expectation is, progress bar will start from 0 once the process start and 100% once the process finished.

Anyone have idea on this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Scope issue: the variables inside `Update-ProcessBar` are *NOT* the variable outside of it.

Given you aren't using that function in other parts, and given how simple it is, just move the contents of the function inside the `While` loop directly:

```
while ($elapsedTime -lt $expectedDuration) {
    $percentage = [math]::Round(($elapsedTime / $expectedDuration) * 100)
    $progressBar.Value = $Percentage
    $labelPercentage.Text = "$Percentage%"
    $form.Refresh()
    $elapsedTime = (Get-Date - $startTime).TotalSeconds
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```